# Last Github for Windows for XP

Tags: github, windows-xp

Because of the nature of MS ClickOnce delivery, Github.application always refer to latest version. Through trials I found 1.0.57 being the last version for XP (I already check wayback machine that starting with github 2.x require .net 4.5).

the steps are:

- Download the manifest from http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_1_0_57_0/GitHub.exe.manifest
- From reading the manifest, batch download all dependencies by appending ".deploy" to file url e.g. http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_1_0_57_0/GitHub.exe.deploy
- Once all files downloaded, remove ".deploy" extension

I ran github.exe and login to my account, once logged-in after a moment (I don't do anything yet) it crashed. I don't know if it become incompatible or I missed some steps.

note:
I need it because I need to maintain/update/test legacy software on XP machine but I want to avoid the complex msysgit client.

Comment: XP has been end-of-life for **years** now, and github.com obviously can't be bothered to make sure everything works on this legacy system. I'll be brutally honest with you: You shouldn't use Windows XP at all, and even less for active development. If you just need to check out a git branch remotely, you don't need the github GUI - simply use command line git.

Comment: The client isn't complex. it's normal git. You just `git clone` / `git pull` /... like the rest of us :) In fact, it being a CLI program only has advantages: you can easily script getting the current state from your repo.

Comment: I'm hired by the manufacturer company *who own the machine*.

Comment: as I only hired, I need to train the staff to able to do minor maintenance which why I choose GUI

Answer (score 0):

don't worry the way you installed your application is correct and there is  noth8ng wrong with it. The application might have crashed due to overload of temporary files on the system. The best way is to delete the temporary or temp files and  run the application again. The steps to delete temp files are 
Start cmd application  by  holding  the windows key and press r .

Type %temp% and click ok

A folder will open with the name removing it 
Select all the files  and delete it.
Some files may not be deleted so in that case you can skip those files.

Now run the application again

Answer (score 0):

I try version 1.0.36 (with the same step I explained in the question) and it have been works so far (never crashed yet), I haven't tried version 1.0.4x but just in case someone need this info.